# ReactJS V16 How to pass parent function to grandchild event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am relatively new to ReactJS and a novice with JavaScript and have been following some online tutorials to learn ReactJS. I am coming across a mixture of tutorials and information from different versions so I am sure I either completely don't understand a topic or am mixing things up here.

I have a function **updateActiveFlag** in my top level object **App** and I am passing it to **ItemGroup** as a prop and then **Item** that I want called when a checkbox is selected. Eventually when I understand what I am doing wrong I will modify other aspects of the state in this same manner as well.

When I select the checkbox, I get in the console:

undefined
 
undefined
 
4  // Assuming I selected the 5th checkbox, this aspect is working correct

Can someone help explain the mistake I am making. It seems that by the time I get back to the top level handler, the concept of 'this' has been lost. At this time I am not interested in using some library to solve this Unless that is the only way. I am hoping it can be solved in this example so that I can first better understand the low level aspects, then I can consider a more proper way if one exists.

**EDIT:**

This is now working

Several responses to this post highlighted a typo I made in my example. I copy and pasted the code form a larger prototype and mixed up the signatures in ItemGroup and Item, so that is reflected in the sample code.

I also changed how I passed the event handler in the App control again based on feedback in this thread and now it is working as I need.

Finally the duplicate topic that was referenced had more information to help me understand this better.
I am not sure how to credit an answer in this case.

```
const Item = (props) => {
return (
      <li className="row">
         <input className="col-sm-1" type="checkbox" checked={props.item.Active} onChange={() => props.activeFlagHandler(props.index)} />
         <div className="col-sm-2">{props.index}</div>
         <div className="col-sm-3">{props.item.Name}</div>
         <div className="col-sm-3">{props.item.Desc}</div>
         <div className="col-sm-3">{props.item.Amount}</div>
      </li>
   );
};


const ItemGroup = (props) => {
   return (
      <div className="container">
         <h4>{props.name}</h4>
      <ul>
            {props.items.map((item, index) => <Item item={item} index={index} activeFlagHandler={props.activeFlagHandler}/>)}
      </ul>
      </div>
   );
};


class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         Name: "",

         "Accounts": [],
         "Expenses": []
      };
   };


   loadModel( model ) {
      $.getJSON( 'api/UnitTest' ).then();

      // Using arrow function otherwise would get an error saying setState is not a valid function
      // because of binding. Arrow function passes ensures correct execution context is passed along
      $.getJSON( '/Model/0123456789' ).then( (results) => { this.processModel( results ) } );
   };


   processModel( results ) {
      console.log( results );

      this.setState( results );
   };


   updateActiveFlag( index ) {
         //const newState = Object.assign( {}, this.state );
         console.log( this.state );
         console.log( this.prevState );

         console.log( index );
   };


   componentDidMount() {
      this.loadModel( '0123456789' );
   }


   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h2>Hello World  {this.state.Name} </h2>
            <ItemGroup name="Expenses" items={this.state.Expenses} activeFlagHandler={(index)=>{this.updateActiveFlag(index)} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Thanks for any help
**strong text**

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to do in the updateActiveFlag method. Are you trying to get information from the checkbox itself? I will say that prevState doesn't exist in that context.

Comment: @JayJordan At this time I am trying to understand why I cant access this.state or this.prevState in the handler. Once I can access the state, I will do actual work using the supplied index. Thanks.

Comment: basically change all your functions to arrow function so *this* does not get lost within callbacks.  See if that works

Comment: Apart from following the duplicate to solve the binding issue, you need to change `<input className="col-sm-1" type="checkbox" checked={props.item.Active} onChange={props.activeFlagHandler(props.index)} />` to `<input className="col-sm-1" type="checkbox" checked={props.item.Active} onChange={() => props.activeFlagHandler(props.index)} />`, notice the onChange being changed to arrow function, otherwise the onChange function will be called on each render

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I had tried some variations similar to the duplicate you showed me, but can into an error related to not being able to define arrow functions as class properties. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398645/unable-to-use-arrow-functions-inside-react-component-class. You answer also made me realise I had a typo in my example code that I copy and pasted from the bigger application. I will edit this question with my new findings. Thanks.

Comment: What issue do you face now

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I actually have it working now thanks to the link you provided and another response in here. I am going to edit the question shortly to reflect that. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Glad it worked out, consider upvoting the answers that helped you

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption about `this` being change is right. In JavaScript `this` depends on from where the function is called (so called *execution context*). There are few ways to overcome this one is using the `bind` method like this

```
 constructor(){
   //...
   this.updateActiveFlag = this.updateActiveFlag.bind(this)
 }
```

That way `this` will stay the same (`App`) no matter where the function is called from (artificially change to *declaration context*). When passing bound method use the direct form.

```
 activeFlagHandler={props.activeFlagHandler}
```

passing the function itself not the arrow function form of

```
 activeFlagHandler={() => props.activeFlagHandler(props.index)}
```

Which passes a new anonymous function.
Another problem in your code is what you actually pass to `Item` is an anonymous function which receives no arguments (`() => ...`) but inside `Item` you try to pass an argument to it `onChange={props.activeFlagHandler(props.index)}` which is unnecessary.
You have the right idea in my opinion in focusing on one lib at a time a great resource i strongly recommend is react [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) specifically [thinking in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) is very instructive.